# Passwords not working after migration from /etc/shadow to LDAP

Tags: openldap, rhel6

I've migrated RHEL6 user accounts from traditional /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, and /etc/group files to OpenLDAP. However, trying to log in as the migrated users does not work because of incorrect user password errors:

Example (removed) /etc/passwd line:

```
leopetr:x:1005:1005:Leo Petr:/mnt/home/leopetr:/bin/bash
```

Example (removed) /etc/shadow line:

```
leopetr:$6$+7sZw4ID$CyLfaFeo.aDn1Xd5.MCBWXDm131CIOPExg0hgUQb4sdInuXIf4IBU8LxJo7Hz144uIp3nYB6cmnIzLAyI6fzr.:16205:0:99999:7:::
```

(The hash corresponds to a randomly generated password for an unprivileged account.)

Example LDIF generated by OpenLDAP conversion tools:

```
dn: uid=leopetr,ou=People,dc=imdemocloud,dc=com
uid: leopetr
cn: Leo Petr
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}$6$+7sZw4ID$CyLfaFeo.aDn1Xd5.MCBWXDm131CIOPExg0hgUQb4sdInuXIf4IBU8LxJo7Hz144uIp3nYB6cmnIzLAyI6fzr.
shadowLastChange: 16205
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1005
gidNumber: 1005
homeDirectory: /mnt/home/leopetr
gecos: Leo Petr
```

I can `su -` to that user account as root, so the user record is accessible in LDAP. However, I can't log in as that user. Example:

```
$ su - leopetr
Password:
su: incorrect password
```

1. Why isn't the password working?
2. Is `{crypt}` the right prefix for a sha-512 password hash?
3. Is `userPassword` the right LDAP field for a password hash?

**Edit**: `/etc/pam.d/su`

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth       sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        include     system-auth
account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account     include     system-auth
password    include     system-auth
session     include     system-auth
session     optional    pam_xauth.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=8 dcredit=-1 ucredit=0 lcredit=-1 ocredit=0 type= reject_username
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

`/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
services = nss, pam
domains = LOCAL,LDAP

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3
entry_cache_timeout = 300
entry_cache_nowait_percentage = 75

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3
offline_credentials_expiration = 2
offline_failed_login_attempts = 3
offline_failed_login_delay = 5

[domain/LDAP]
cache_credentials = true

id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldaps://my_hostname.my_domain.com
ldap_search_base = dc=my_domain,dc=com
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# The entry '[NOTFOUND=return]' means that the search for an
# entry should stop if the search in the previous entry turned
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Valid entries include:
#
#   nisplus         Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#   nis         Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#   dns         Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#   files           Use the local files
#   db          Use the local database (.db) files
#   compat          Use NIS on compat mode
#   hesiod          Use Hesiod for user lookups
#   [NOTFOUND=return]   Stop searching if not found so far
#

# To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis

passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss ldap

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss ldap

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss ldap
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Also, here are the `authconfig` commands I used:

```
authconfig --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enablelocauthorize --enableldap --enableldapauth \
--ldapserver=ldaps://my_hostname.my_domain.com:636 --disableldaptls \
--ldapbasedn=dc=my_domain,dc=com \
--enablerfc2307bis --enablemkhomedir --enablecachecreds --update

authconfig --update --enablesssd --enablesssdauth

authconfig --enablesssd --update
```

Comment: Can you reset your password directly to LDAP and retry? From your description seems like you've copied the hashed password from /etc/shadow to the openldap entry. Normally you should reset it with an ldif (or use ApacheDirectoryStudio, whatever fits)

Comment: The contents of `/etc/pam.d/su` and all files included in that file, recursive, are relevant. As are `/etc/ldap.conf` or `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` depending on your setup.

Comment: @84104 I've added `/etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to the question

Comment: Be sure you have sssd on your passwd and shadow entries on `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Another thing, on RH6 use authconfig to enable ldap users

Comment: @Fredi I've added q/etc/nsswitch.confq and `authconfig` commands to the question

Answer (score 1):

No, the correct tag for SHA-512 is `{SHA-512}` but you have to enable a module and to apply an overlay to your data database.

Why not simply generating user passwords with:

```
sudo ldappasswd -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL uid=leopetr,ou=People,dc=imdemocloud,dc=com -s secret
```

If you want to pre-stage password (for ldif ldapmodify insert), have a look at `slappasswd`, a tool to generate password in the correct format.

Yes, `userPassword` is fine.

Comment: I need something that can be automated and doesn't require knowing the user passwords, just hashes. I've tried modifying the `userPassword` for that user to start with `{SSHA}` or `{SHA-512}` instead of `{crypt}`, but the error hasn't changed. I'm looking into whether there are any modules I need to load.

Answer (score 1):

When migrating password hashes from /etc/shadow to LDAP entries the correct LDAP password scheme to use is {CRYPT}, no matter what crypt(3) scheme is used.

The disadvantage is that those password hashes are platform-specific and are thus not always portable. You can see which schemes are available on your specific Linux/FreeBSD/whatever platform in the crypt(3) man-page installed on your system.

Besides this you should not use a remote *shadow* map at all, especially since exposing the hashes of all user passwords to all systems via LDAP is horrible security practice.

*sssd* or *nss-pam-ldapd* will send LDAP simple bind requests for checking user's password. Therefore they don't need read access to password hashes.